# JQ if then statement scope

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'd like to use JQ to grab only the sub-records that match an if-then statement. When I use

`jq 'if .services[].banner == "FQMDAAICCg==" then .services[].port else empty end`

it grabs all of the ports for the record. (there are multiple services under each record and I want to restrict my then statement to only the services scope where I actually found the if condition).

How do I just get the port, banner, etc. for the specific service underneath the record which hit my condition?

example:

```
{
  "services": [
    {
      "tls_detected": false,
      "banner_is_raw": true,
      "transport_protocol": "tcp",
      "banner": "PCFET0NUWVBFIEhU",
      "certificate": null,
      "timestamp": "2020-03-22T00:38:01.074Z",
      "protocol": null,
      "port": 4444
    },
    {
      "tls_detected": false,
      "banner_is_raw": true,
      "transport_protocol": "tcp",
      "banner": "SFRUUC8xLjEgMzA",
      "certificate": null,
      "timestamp": "2020-03-19T01:39:45.288Z",
      "protocol": null,
      "port": 8080
    },
    {
      "tls_detected": false,
      "banner_is_raw": true,
      "transport_protocol": "tcp",
      "banner": "FQMDAAICCg==",
      "certificate": null,
      "timestamp": "2020-03-19T01:39:45.288Z",
      "protocol": null,
      "port": 8085
    },
    {
      "tls_detected": false,
      "banner_is_raw": false,
      "transport_protocol": "tcp",
      "banner": "Q2FjaGUtQ29ud",
      "certificate": null,
      "timestamp": "2020-03-20T04:25:24Z",
      "protocol": "http",
      "port": 8080
    }
  ],
  "ip": "103.238.62.68",
  "autonomous_system": {
    "description": "CHAPTECH-AS-AP Chaptech Pty Ltd",
    "asn": 133493,
    "routed_prefix": "103.238.62.0/24",
    "country_code": "AU",
    "name": "CHAPTECH-AS-AP Chaptech Pty Ltd",
    "path": [
      11164,
      3491,
      63956,
      7594,
      7594,
      7594,
      7594,
      133493
    ]
  },
  "location": {
    "country_code": "AU",
    "registered_country": "Australia",
    "registered_country_code": "AU",
    "continent": "Oceania",
    "timezone": "Australia/Sydney",
    "latitude": -33.494,
    "longitude": 143.2104,
    "country": "Australia"
  }
}
```

Update:

Thanks to peak but I couldn't get the additional goals bit working below. I ended up using

```
jq 'select(.services[].banner == "FQMDAAICCg==") | {port: .services[].port, banner: .services[].banner, ip: .ip}' censys.json | jq 'if .banner == "FQMDAAICCg==" then .ip,.port else empty end'
```

which is ugly but did the trick and still allowed me to stream the data to the first filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Original question

> How do I just get the port, banner, etc. for the specific service underneath the record which hit my condition?

To get just the "port" for the service matching the condition, you could modify your query:

```
.services[]
| if .banner == "FQMDAAICCg==" then .port else empty end
```

Equivalently:

```
.services[]
| select(.banner == "FQMDAAICCg==")
| .port
```

### Additional goal

> I want to end up in this example with '8085' + '103.238.62.68'

If you really want the two values in that format, you could write something along the following lines, invoking jq with the -r option:

```
.ip as $ip
| (.services[] | select(.banner == "FQMDAAICCg==") | .port) as $port
| "'\($port)' + '\($ip)'"
```

or more briefly but less readably:

```
"'\(.services[] | select(.banner == "FQMDAAICCg==") | .port)' + '\(.ip)'"
```

Comment: the first part works great thanks - i'm struggling with the additional goal though: is that how you would actually enter the command?

Comment: The newlines are optional. I’d suggest using the -f command-line option if you’re having trouble quoting the jq command for your shell.

Comment: looks like too much data for -f.

i've tried:
```
jq -r '.ip as $ip | .services[] | if .banner == "FQMDAAICCg==" then .port as $port else empty end' censys.json
```
and
```
jq '.ip as $ip | (.services[] | select(.banner == "FQMDAAICCg==")| .port) as $port' censys.json
```
to no avail. sorry - anything obvious wrong with the latter?

Comment: You will need to review the basic usage of jq.  The simplest is to use an invocation like: `jq -rf PROGRAM.jq censys.json`

Comment: @DanielLee ...starting a jq program with a `#!/usr/bin/jq -rf` shebang is an easy way to get that effect; then shell quoting becomes completely moot, and one can put *only* jq code in the file, formatted however one wants.